# How can i create header "createtopmaterialnavigator" in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am creating a material top navigator with my own routes, but I can't set a default header like in other navigation options like stack navigator.

I try to do so much thing and I waste so much time in this.

I am using react-navigation v3.0 and I have 4 navigations in my application (DrawerNavigation,SwichNavigation StackNavigation, and TopTabNavigation).

Someone know how to create or a custom TopTabNavigation or set a default header in this navigation.

Comment: Please provide some background and show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap your tabNavigator inside a stackNavigator (using one global header) or have every child of your tabNavigator be a stackNavigator (handling every tab header separately)